# Cancelling a ROS action within an executive_teer node

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying out the [executive_teer](http://www.ros.org/wiki/executive_teer) package and my test setup is a simulated TurtleBot running two main tasks: a navigation task that moves the TurtleBot through a series of waypoints in a map using MoveBase actions and a battery_check task that monitors a simulated battery level and sends the robot to a charging base (also using MoveBase) when the level falls too low.

The trouble I am having is interrupting the current MoveBaseAction from the battery_check task when the battery level falls below threshold and while the robot is still on the way to a waypoint.  Even though I send a move_base.cancel_goal() from the battery_check task, the robot always continues to the current waypoint before then heading to the charging station.  I've also tried killing or pausing the navigation task but I get the same result--the MoveBaseAction appears to be outside the teer environment's control.

I can post the code details if necessary but perhaps there is some general trick when using teer with standard ROS actions?

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59996/cancelling-a-ros-action-within-an-executive_teer-node/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2013-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer given by Patrick works, but misses the point of teer.  A better solution would be to have `self.move_base_done` as a ConditionVariable, so that the co-routine is automatically un-paused when this variable becomes true. Please see [this tutorial page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/executive_teer/Tutorials/Wait%20Conditions) for more informations about condition variables.

---

Originally posted by [Stéphane Magnenat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1250/st%C3%A9phane-magnenat/) with karma: 83 on 2013-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-04-08**:
Thanks for the clarification @Stéphane Magnenat.